# Python-Entering with binary number

Tags: python, binary

How can I make de user enter with a binary number? 
and after I saved that in a variable how I can break the number in 2 equal parts?Like:

number = 11110000

results:

number1 = 1111
number2 = 0000

Comment: Use `input` (or `raw_input` if you're on Python 2) and slicing.

Answer (score 0):

To take what would be a string and make it in to binary representation, you can do this:

```
number = [bool(int(x)) for x in '11110000']
number1 = number[:4]
number2 = number[4:]
```